# MacBook: Prevent mouse from switching to external monitor placed above main display

Tags: macos, display, mojave, software

So I got an external monitor witch is positioned above my MacBook. Sometimes I want to use the Menu bar of my MacBook, and I often move my mouse too quickly and it goes to the secondary monitor.

Is there a button I can press to prevent my mouse from going to my secondary monitor, but instead trigger the menu bar to pop up in fullscreen mode?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest simply changing the arrangement of the screens (in the dialog seen in your screenshot, not physically).

You can either place the screen to the side, or even just place it at an offset. Say you place it as far to the right as possible (while remaining above the main screen). In that case, you could move the mouse from one screen to the other by going all the way to the right edge of the screen and up.

Comment: I tried this but it is not so intuitive as otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A convenient approach in this case could be to invoke the Menu Bar using the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

[image]

You can also customize the shortcut to your linking by going to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts, select **Keyboard** in the left pane. Look for **Move focus to the menu bar** entry in the right pane.

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Answer (score -1):

To keep your mouse cursor from jumping to the above external screen when trying to access the menu-bar on the screen below you could employ a 'sticky-cursor', or 'cursor bounce' feature so there is a pause, or bounce before your cursor moves to the screen above. Your idea of a button you can press to achieve this is also doable using a feature on **Edgecase**—an app created for your type of situation.

EdgeCase is available at the Mac Store for about 5 dollars.

I set up a cursor pause between screens on a Ubuntu desktop connected to my Macbook Pro desktop by using a Ubuntu feature that was practically built-in, which is how I knew there *had* to be a solution.

Good luck!

Comment: How do you do what you say in the first paragraph

Comment: That should be edited into your answer